# Segmentation fault in reading a file and writing it to a char vector

Tags: c++, file, vector

Following is a code written by me to read a file and store it in a char vector.

```
#include <fstream>
#include "Graph.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using std::ifstream;
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

static int const WIDTH = 50;

vector<char>* read_file(ifstream*);

int main(){

    ifstream file;
    vector<char>* buf;
    file.open("myfile");
    if(file.is_open()){ 
        buf = read_file(&file);
    }


//  Graph graphObj;
  //  graphObj.populateGraph(buffer);   
}

vector<char>* read_file(ifstream* refFile){
    vector<char>* buffer = new vector<char>();
    int pos = 0;  

    while(!(refFile->eof())){
         refFile->read((((char*)(buffer))+pos),WIDTH); 
         pos += WIDTH;  // update the pos with the number of characters read earlier

 }      
    return buffer;
}
```

The code compiles, but I am getting a segmentation fault due to a reason which is not clear to me. Can anyone help me on why I am getting a seg fault?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `buffer->push_back()`? In any case, there's a problem with this vector being a `char` vector if you want to store more than 1 `char` per entry.

Comment: You're blatantly violating aliasing. What makes you believe casting a `std::vector<char>*` to `char*` is a *good* idea? Maybe keep it [a little simpler](http://pastebin.com/iSDeYRLE).

Comment: You seem to be coming from a C background. Yes vector is continuous storage but it has to be allocated, you don't do that anywhere. Also it's a class which you cannot simply cast to char*. Also, don't use raw pointers. Just return the vector by value and the ifstream by reference.

Comment: Haven't I allocated memory with the "new" keyword inside the function?

Comment: Yes, but just for the vector instance. Not for it's storage. Moreover you shouldn't be using `new` here but just allocate it on the stack and return by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handling of the `std::vector<char>` needs to be updated.

1. You have not allocated any memory in the `std::vector` to hold any items.
2. You are using `buffer` as though it is a pointer to an array of `char`s.

   ```
     refFile->read((((char*)(buffer))+pos),WIDTH);
   ```

   Type casting `buffer` to `char*`, as you do above, is cause for undefined behavior.

You can solve poth problems by reading one character at a time and adding them to the `std::vector`, or reading an array of characters and adding them to the `std::vector` one character at a time.

1. First method.

   ```
   vector<char>* read_file(ifstream* refFile){
      vector<char>* buffer = new vector<char>();
      int pos = 0;  

      int c;    
      while( (c = refFile->get()) != EOF ){
         buffer->push_back(static_cast<char>(c));    
      }      
      return buffer;
   }
   ```
2. Second method.

   ```
   vector<char>* read_file(ifstream* refFile){
      vector<char>* buffer = new vector<char>();
      char temp[WIDTH];
      while( (refFile->read(temp, WIDTH))){
         std::streamsize count = refFile->gcount();
         for (std::streamsize i = 0; i < count; ++i ) {
            buffer->push_back(temp[i]);
         }      
      }      
      return buffer;
   }
   ```

I don't see any reason why you are creating `std::vector` from the heap instead of creating it on the stack and returning an object instead of a pointer. You are adding complexity to your code without much to gain.

Also, you should pass a `ifstream&` to `read_file` instead of `ifstream*`.

```
vector<char> read_file(ifstream& refFile){
   vector<char> buffer;
   int pos = 0;  

   int c;    
   while( (c = refFile.get()) != EOF ){
      bufferpush_back(static_cast<char>(c));    
   }      
   return buffer;
}

int main(){

    ifstream file;
    vector<char> buf;
    file.open("myfile");
    if(file.is_open()){ 
        buf = read_file(file);
    }
}
```

Now, you don't have to worry about `delete`ing `buf`.

Comment: why do you say that I havent allocated memory for the vector, when I have allocated with  the new keyword?

Comment: @DesirePRG because you haven't. Just because you (unnecessarily) `new`-ed a `std::vector<>` doesn't mean the vector *itself* has an space allocated within. A trivial example. `struct S { char *p; }; S *s = new S;` We just allocated a dynamic S. That's doesn't mean `s->p` magically points to valid data yet.